# Selecting observations with nested unique function in Pandas

Tags: pandas

I am relatively new to Pandas and I still have old R habits.
Essentially, I am trying to select observations that is using unique function to select the value.
Using the titanic data:

```
titanic.loc[titanic['Sex'] == titanic.Sex.unique()[[0]].tolist(), ]
```

Where titanic.Sex.unique()[[0]].tolist() gives:

```
>>> titanic.Sex.unique()[[0]].tolist()
['male']
```

Any suggestion to making this work?
Thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `==` to `isin`

```
titanic.loc[titanic['Sex'].isin(titanic.Sex.unique()[[0]].tolist()), ]
```

Comment: thanks!  I knew it was something simple....  Now, I just need to forget some R tricks I know.

Comment: @stuski yw : -) also  `titanic.loc[titanic['Sex']== titanic.Sex.unique().tolist()[0], :] ` will work

Answer (score 0):

How about

titanic[titanic['Sex'] == list( titanic['Sex'].unique() )[0]]

?